# When can an automorphism of the fundamental group be written as the induced isomorphism of some self-homeomorphism?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

It is a common exercise to show that both automorphisms of $\pi_1(S^1)$ can be realized as induced isomorphisms of self-homeomorphisms of $S^1$. It is natural to ask if this is the case for spaces other than $S^1$.

> Let $X$ be a topological space. For which $X$ and $\eta \in \operatorname{Aut}(\pi_1(X))$ is it true that $\eta = \varphi_\ast$ for some self-homeomorphism $\varphi: X \to X$?

The answer to this more general question is "all of them" where $X = \bigwedge_{1}^n S^1$ and *seems* to be "all of them" for $X = \sharp_1^n T^m$.

I have not yet found such a pair $(X, \eta)$ for which there is no such self-homeomorphism.

Comment: $X=S^1\vee S^1$ should do the job.

Comment: The meaningful question to ask is: Suppose $X$ is a topological manifold and $f: X\to X$ is a homotopy-equivalence. When is $f$ induced by a homeomorphism of $X$? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_conjecture for the discussion in the case of aspherical manifolds; see also here http://131.220.77.52/lueck/data/banff_rigidity070228trans.pdf for the discussion of non-aspherical case. 

Comment: There are also some homotopy-theoretic obstructions (to finding a self-homotopy-equivalence inducing the given automorphism of $\pi_1$). For instance, $\pi_1(X)$ could be $Z^2$, where the two free generators $a, b$ act very differently on the higher homotopy groups: Say, $a$ can act trivially and $b$ can act nontrivially; so the automorphism of $Z^2$ swapping the generators will give you more examples. Take a look at  Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" book to see what is needed for a self-map of $X$ to be a homotopy-equivalence (in terms of homotopy groups).   

Comment: @Misha: Your second link is broken; the file is now located at <https://www.him.uni-bonn.de/lueck/data/banff_rigidity070228trans.pdf>.

Comment: **(a)**  first, for a self-homeomorphism $f$, the map $f_*$ in $\pi_1$ does not make sense in general. It makes sense for a *pointed* self-homeomorphism. (However if $X$ is path-connected and $\pi_1$ is abelian it's base-point independent.)

**(b)** for another simple counterexample, just decorate the circle, e.g. by planting three little rooted trees which break the reversing symmetry (still path-connected, the $\pi_1$ is still $\mathbf{Z}$ but the non-trivial automorphism is not induced by a self-homeomorphism).

Comment: @Misha why the manifold case should be "**the**" meaningful question to ask? it's an important but very particular setting.

Comment: @YCor : The posted answer summaries this rather well. In order to obtain even mildly nontrivial positive results about existence of a homotopy-equivalence one usually needs a space homotopy-equivalent to a finite CW complex. Next, to be able to promote a homotopy-equivalence to a homeomorphism, one usually needs topological homogeneity. Tame manifolds are the most natural class when the two conditions hold. One can in principle add to this list Q-manifolds (infinite-dimensional spaces modeled on the Hilbert cube) and generalized manifolds of Bryant-Ferry-Mio-Weinberger.

Comment: ... However, for the latter class homogeneity is still (after 25 years) an open problem. So, this leaves us with manifolds and Q-manifolds.

Answer (score 6):

To summarize what was posted in the comments by Henrik Rüping and Misha:

There are two possible obstructions to this being true.  The first is that not every homotopy-equivalence descends to a homeomorphism.  This phenomenon is the subject of the (unsolved as of 2019) [Borel conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_conjecture) (also discussed [here](http://him.uni-bonn.de/lueck/data/banff_rigidity070228trans.pdf)).  The second is that not every automorphism of $\pi_1$ generates a homotopy-equivalence — there may be higher-dimensional obstructions!

To make this concrete, consider the following examples.

For the first obstruction, let $X=S^1\vee S^1$.  Call the generators of the fundamental groups of each copy of $S^1$ be $a$ and $b$; then by e.g. the Seifert-van Kampen theorem, $\pi_1(X)$ is the free group $\langle a,b\rangle$.  Thus $a\mapsto a, b\mapsto ab$ defines an automorphism of $\pi_1(X)$.

But we can classify the self-homemorphisms of $X$ quite easily.  Fix a self-homoeomorphism $f$.  For each point $p\in X$, choose a small neighborhood $N_p$ and count the connected components of $N\setminus\{p\}$.  This number must be preserved by $f$, so we must have $f(o)=o$, where $o$ is the join point of $X$.  Moreover, $f$ must map the components of $N_o\setminus\{o\}$ to each other, and they must map in such a way that they can be extended to the remainder of each circle.  So the group of self-homeomorphisms is generated by the distortions of each circle and exchanging the two circles.  None of these induce $a\mapsto a, b\mapsto ab$.

(To see that this is a homotopy-equivalence that does not descend to a homeomorphism, try to visualize how this automorphism of $\pi_1$ affects the universal cover.)

For the second obstruction, let $f$ be a self-homeomorphism of $S^2$ with nontrivial degree $d$.  Consider $Y=S^1\times[0,1]\times S^2$, and let $X=Y/(x,0,z)\sim(x,1,f(z))$.  $X$ is a nontrivial fiber bundle of $S^2$ over the torus, $S^1\times[0,1]/(x,0)\sim(x,1)\approx S^1\times S^1$.  Now, $\pi_1(S^2)=0$, so $\pi_1(X)=\pi_1(S^1\times S^1)$.  For each circle in the torus, $\pi_1(S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}$; let the generators be $a$ and $b$.  Then $\pi_1(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$ and certainly $a\mapsto b,b\mapsto a$ is an automorphism thereof.

The situation is reversed in degree $2$: only the 2-sphere contributes to $\pi_2$, so that $\pi_2(X)=\pi_2(S^2)\cong\mathbb{Z}$.  But now $a$ and $b$ can be distinguished: $a$ acts trivially on $\pi_2(X)$, but $b$ acts as translation by $d$.  Thus $a\mapsto b,b\mapsto a$ cannot be extended to an automorphism of $\pi_2(X)$.

Comment: One can also reverse the circles (maybe this counts as a distortion?) but of course that doesn't affect the main point. Also, the only possible degrees of a self-homeomorphism of $S^2$ are $1$ and $-1$, so I guess $d=-1$.